# User Control not loading when container panel is invisible

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol which has a combobox inside it.

This UserControl is the inside an asp panel - and when the panel is visible, the dropdownlist within the control binds to its datasource and behaves itself.

When the panel visibility is set to false, the dropdownlist within the usercontrol is empty.

Any help appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: It it a desired behaviour that your Dropdownlist is empty when the panel is invisible? I ask because it does make sense that the Dropdown is only bound to the Datasource when its visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the Visible property of the panel to false means that none of its controls are rendered. If you want it to be rendered but invisible on your page, use the CSS style `display:none;` on the panel.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this out but have run into a problem.

I keep getting a javascript error saying that the panel is not defined.

I am applying to button as follow:
imb_SearchMain.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:togglePanel(false," & pnl_Search.ClientID & ");")

The function:
function togglePanel(showIt, pnl) {
  if (showIt) {
    $find(pnl)._show;
  } else {
    $find(pnl)._hide;
  }
}

thanks.

Comment: Have you set your panel.Visible to true now?

Comment: It is set to be visible by default yes (although I have not set the property).

Comment: Ok, so I got it working using non-jquery code. Thanks for the tip!